# How to get status code when using EventSource in chrome?

Tags: javascript, http, server-sent-events

I have tried to use the native `EventSource` in Google Chrome. If the server responds with an error, details about this response will be shown in the response header in Chrome inspect:

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6iXJ.png)

But it seems to be impossible to get the response status code from the `error` parameter. Neither with the callback function `onerror` nor with the listener handler (`source.addEventListener('error',function (error){})`).

```js
    let source = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:7071/sse?access_token=xxxxxxx')
    source.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    };

    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log('Unknown event with message :' + event.data)
    };

    source.addEventListener('log',function (event) {
        console.log('log event with message :' + event.data)
    });

    source.addEventListener('error',function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

So, is there another way to get the response details in code?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the best way is to not use native EventSource but instead using something like:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/fetch-event-source

Answer (score -3):

Not at the moment, but you can set a error handler like this:

```js
source.onerror = function(err) {
  console.error("EventSource failed:", err);
};
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events